# Какой знак препинания здесь нужно применить?

Tags: пунктуация

Незабываемые приятные эмоции гарантированы.

Answer (score 2):

Трудно говорить о знаках препинания, если сама фраза невразумительная. Приятные - это одно. Незабываемые - совсем другое. Не чувствуете, что второе определение (не скажу эпитет) гораздо слабее, чем первое? А стоят рядом. Вот и думай: однородные они или нет?

Comment: А если использовать одно прилагательное, тогда какой знак препинания нужен после "эмоций"?

Comment: Никакого не нужно. Хотите акцентировать на "гарантированы" - поставьте тире. В каком-нибудь рекламном буклете, где важно "покричать", тире будет уместно. Еще и восклицательный знак в конце. В обычном тексте - нет.

"Приятные эмоции" ведь тоже плоховато сказано. Приятными бывают впечатления, а эмоции бывают... ну, положительными, например (первое, что в голову пришло). Незабываемыми тоже могут быть.